# Visual Studio 2015 “non-standard syntax; use '&' to create pointer for member”

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers

While creating thread using CreateThread() in Win32 Application , I am getting this error . 
In CreateThread(NULL,0,pSample->Resize(),NULL,0,NULL);  It shows error in function calling .

I do have several files as :

**Main.cpp**

```
WinMain()
 {
   //Create sample
    return Win32Appliaction::Run(&sample);
  }
```

**Win32Application.cpp**

```
int Win32Application::Run(DXSample* pSample)
  {
     //Create Window
     pSample->Init();
     pSample->Render();
     CreateThread(NULL,0,pSample->Resize,NULL,0,NULL);//error occurs
     pSample->Destroy();
  }
```

**DXSample.h**

```
class DXSample
   {
     public:
           virtual void Init() =0; //and rest all functions
   };
```

**HelloTexture.h**

```
 class HelloTexture:public DXSample
   {
       public : 
             virtual void Init();//all other functions similarly
    }
```

**HelloTexture.cpp**

```
void Hellotexture::Init()
 { //code
  } 
 void Hellotexture::Resize()
 {
    //code 
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter #2 of the CreateThread must be a pointer to function matching [ThreadProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686736(v=vs.85).aspx) signature. You can not pass result of pSample->Resize() (which is void) or a pointer to Resize function itself (because this is a non-static class member function). Also you may want to use ::std::thread instead of calling WinApi directly.

Comment: I tried using std::thread , it doesn't work for win32 Application . Switching to CreateThread() . Can you please suggest an edit for the program to work.

Comment: std::thread should work fine for win32 applications, but if you want to use CreateThread anyway then you thread entry point should look like DWORD WINAPI ResizeThreadProc(LPVOID lpParameter){ static_cast< DXSample * >(lpParameter)->Resize();} and you pass a pointer to DXSample as parameter #3 when creating thread CreateThread(NULL,0, &ResizeThreadProc, pSample,0,NULL);

Answer (score 0):

You are *calling* the `pSample->Resize()` function, passing the returned value to the `CreateFunction` as the function to run.

If you want the `Resize` function to be run in its own thread there are two things you need to do:

1. Pass a pointer to the function instead, e.g. `&HelloTexture::Resize`.
2. Make the function `static`.

The first point is about passing a pointer to the function itself to `CreateThread`, who will create the thread and *call* the function from the new thread.

The second point is because non-static member function needs an *object*, an *instance* of the class to be called on.

---

There are also another problem with the code you have. Remember that threads are running parallel to each other. If you create a thread it will run independently from other threads. That means the object you use, and all its data, must be kept alive until the end of the thread.

I'm bringing this up because you seemingly want to create the thread, and then immediately call `pSample->Destroy()` which is like pulling the rug out from under some other persons feet.

Do you really want to create a thread here?

Comment: Yes there are two separate things happening . I want to create a thread to resize an image buffer and store it and parallel to that I want to render a figure . The pSample->Destroy() call just destroy the display window and nothing else .

Comment: thank you for suggesting edits . I tried both of them . The first one shows error . It says that argument of type void(*)() aint compatible with LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE . For the second point "pSample" here is used to call the function . It must be a necessity to make function static

Comment: @shero_don Are you saying you will do two possible conflicting things at the same time with the same data? What does `Resize` do? Shouldn't you be calling it first, and then render, in serial? The little code you show just doesn't make sense, especially as threads.

Comment: I have created  copies of data . one is being resized while other is used to render.